# What word was he talking about?

Tags: word

Ollie, my friend, says:

"Take away "T" from this word and you will take away 63. Take away "T" and then replace the "S" with "L" and you will take away 59!"

What is that word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word may be

> SEVENTY

Take away "T" from this word and you will take away 63.

> SEVENTY - T = SEVEN Y which sounds like 7 why?
>  or better per Stiv,
>  taking away "T" means taking away the "TY" sound, leaving SEVEN (70 - 63)

Take away "T" and then replace the "S" with "L" and you will take away 59

> SEVENTY - T & S → L = LEVEN Y which sounds like 11 (read quickly) why?
>  or, again thanks to Stiv,
>  adding "L" means adding the "EL" sound, ending as ELEVEN (70 - 59)

Ollie may clue

> The [Oliver 70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_70) series of large agricultural tractors produced from 1935 to 1967.

Comment: Another great solve!

Comment: I think you need to focus on the use of the speech marks in your explanation... Then rot13(gnxvat njnl "G" zrnaf gnxvat njnl gur "GL" fbhaq, fvzvyneyl, nqqvat "Y" zrnaf nqqvat gur "RY" fbhaq) and it all works without the extra 'why' issue :)

Comment: Good points @Stiv - I will add in your explanation as it sounds better.